# Rails way: Finding a deeply nested association with many where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

This seems like a simple question but it's a little puzzle to me. I want to find a good way to handle this. 
I have 5 models.

Job

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_entries_jobs
  has_many :job_entries, through: :job_entries_jobs
end
```

JobEntry

```
class JobEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attachments
    has_many :job_entries_jobs
    has_many :pinned_entries, through: :job_entries_jobs
    has_many :jobs, through: :job_entries_jobs
    belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```

JobEntriesJob

```
class JobEntriesJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'job_entries_jobs'
  has_many :pinned_entries
  belongs_to :job_entry
  belongs_to :job, touch: true
end
```

PinnedEntry

```
class PinnedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "pinned_entries"
  belongs_to :job_entries_job
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_entries
  has_many :pinned_entries
end
```

Can I get pinned_entries by using `job_id` and `user_id` ( job_id and user_id get from `request` params) via `associations` in the `rails` way ( I can get pinned_entries by using `SQL` ). If Yes, where should I put this `code`?

How about if I have an `attachment` model

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'attachments'

    belongs_to :job_entry, :class_name => 'JobEntry', :foreign_key => 'job_entry_id'

end
```

And I want to `include` `attachment` ( a link and file name ) and  `JobEntry` ( `content` ) ? 
Here is the output that should be

```
{
  "listPinnedEntries": [
    {
      "id": 1
      "user_id": 
      "text": "content of entry",
      "user": {
        "id": 
        "username": "jamesnguyen"
      },
      "attachments": [
        {
          "id": 
          "job_entry_id":
          "comment": "file name",
          "file": {
            "url": "link here"
          }
        },
        {
         "id": 
          "job_entry_id":
          "comment": "file name",
          "file": {
            "url": "link here"
          }
        }
      ]
    }]
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: try doing `user_id.pinned_entries` in your view which will view all the entries related to that particular `user` .

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated the question a little bit. Could you read it again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `job_id` and `user_id`:

```
user = User.find(user_id)
pinned_entries = user.pinned_entries.includes(:job_entries_job).where(job_entries_jobs: {job_id: job_id})
```

**UPDATE (For the 2nd Question about Attachment):**

Since you are generating a hash of values, it will be easier to modify your PinnedEntry model (or maybe even Job model and User model as @Robin answered) than doing a dirty looping:

```
class PinnedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "pinned_entries"
  belongs_to :job_entries_job
  belongs_to :job_entry, through: :job_entries_job
  has_many :attachments, through: :job_entry
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Then, continued from my 1st answer above:

```
pinned_entries.as_json(
  only: [:id, :user_id, :text],
  include: [
    user: {
      only: [:id, :username]
    },
    attachments: {
      only: [:id, :job_entry_id, :comment]
    }
  ]
)
```

This will return a Hash of values that is the same as what you wanted. Note: I did not include the `file: url` as from your Attachment model, there is no `belongs_to :file` or something that would help me determine the relationship of the Attachment model to `file` and `url`. If it is not an attribute, then I think you'd have to add these to the resulting Hash manually.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How about if I have an `attachment` model and want to include ?

Comment: @JamesNguyen, can you expand on your second question about the attachment model? Is this second question still related to user_id and job_id from the first question, or is this a separate question? What I am getting at is you wanted to retrieve all attachments where link == 'something && file_name == 'somefilename' && the job_entry associated to the attachment has a content == 'somecontent'?

Comment: I want to `include` the association information and reduce the query. I have put the output that should be

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to add an additional [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) to the models `Job` and `User` and link it with your `PinnedEntry` via the [`:through`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

Your `Job` model would change to:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_entries_jobs
  has_many :job_entries, through: :job_entries_jobs
  has_many :pinned_entries: through: :job_entries
end
```

Then you can use `.pinned_entries` as usual on a `Job` record. Accordingly to that you change your `User` model.